# I get “Permission denied (publickey,password)” when trying to SSH into my MacBook Pro running Mojave via my router

Tags: ssh, macbook

Recently I've been trying to establish a remote connection into my laptop. I have turned on “Remote Login” in the sharing settings, and I have configured my router (R515ac) to forward port 22 to my laptop. I'm able to reach my MacBook's IP address, but when I tried to login using

```
ssh myusername@my.macbooks.ip.adress
```

and entered my password, the response I got was:

```
Permission denied. please try again
```

I thought I entered my password wrong so I tried, and then again. However I keep getting denied. The third time it says

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Which is weird, because when I have my other device connected to the same local network as my MacBook, and try to SSH into my MacBook Pro’s internal IP, using the same password, I was able to log in. But as soon as I tried to SSH into my MacBook Pro’s public IP from a different network (with port forwarding configured), I keep getting denied.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please edit your question to add make and model of your router to the question. Sounds like the error from the outside world is coming from SSH being enabled on your router. Thus when you are on the outside of your network it’s attempting to login to the router and not your MacBook Pro. See if your router allows you to disable SSH login in the router and then try again.

Comment: @JakeGould It turns out you're right. I used the username and password of my browser, and I successfully logged in, to my router, not my MacBook. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @JakeGould I also realized that what I thought was port forwarding, was actually NAT. I thought they were the same thing but apparently they weren't. I'm unable to find port forwarding on my router though.

Comment: @JakeGould I disabled SSH on my router (at least I think I did), but it still didn't solve the issue. It's still attempting to login to the router and not my macbook.

Comment: Well, I have never heard of that router before. Is it an ISP provided router? Because if it is your best bet might be to use a second router—one that is more open and flexible—to be your router and set the ISP router to bridge mode.